# Is it allowed to change the background of an UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, background, uisearchbar

I have been searching thru the web but cant find a confirmed answer.
There are ways like removing the subview within the searchbar.subviews but is that allowed?

If not then, aside from changing the tintColor of SearchBar, or use a textfield instead,
is there a way that wont break apple's rule and still being able to customize the background of searchBar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on a shipping app that made the background of the search bar transparent.  There were no problems with this.

Answer (score 1):

You are not breaking apple's rules if you are not conflicting with private API's.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've seen used a lot (albeit only on toolbars and navigation bars, so I'm not 100% sure it'll work the same way): subclass `UISearchBar` and override its `-drawRect:`, drawing your own background image within the view's bounds.

Comment: i used a pretty weird way to make the UISearchBar's background transparent. In the XIB, i drag a UIToolBar and put the UISearchBar inside the UIToolBar. It seems like iOS automatically make the UISearchBar background transparent to match the color of UIToolbar. Then I kinda subclass UIToolBar to override the drawRect of its super ^^; Thanks everyone!! I'd realy appreciate your advices!